# Using solar to recharge a Li-po battery

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, energy, lithium-polymer

I'm looking for help determining what size of solar (PV) I should use to recharge my Li-po battery after discharged.

Battery Characteristics :Capacity:1600mAh

Nominal Voltage: 3.7V

Charging Current:0.2CA=(320mA)

Charging Voltage: 4.2V

Charging time (std):6 to 7 hours

Charging time(max): 2 to 3 hours.

Solar (PV)
I have looked at a couple solar cells like the Digikey solar SM101K09L.
This is a MONOCRYST SOLAR CELL 198MW 6.22V
can anyone help determine how long it would take to charge this battery with the solar cell I have mentioned above? Is there any other product you would recommend?

[Solar panel spec](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=SM101K09L)

Answer (score 0):

A Li-PO battery should never be completely discharged. Its load should be disconnected when its voltage drops to 3V to 3.2V.
A Li-PO is dangerous if it is not properly charged by a battery charger circuit designed for it.